# Office.Interop.Word - How to print the document on both sides?

Tags: c#, printing, office-interop

I print documents (batch print) using `Word.Document.PrintOut` method. How can I print a document on both sides?

In the **MS Word** interface it can be done through the **File**->**Print**->**Print on Both Sides** option.

Word 2010, C#, .NET 3.5

---

Many thanks to John for his answer (+1)! There are results of my research:

1. I went to the first path that John recommends, found a few additional
   articles, like "classic" article on **CodeProject** ([Changing printer
   settings using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6899/Changing-printer-settings-using-C)) and [several others](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238860-using-setprinter-c-set-duplex-option-print-prefs) derived from it. In the end, I
   got compiled code which was to set a Duplex property, but like many
   others "victims" of this article - this code did not work :)
2. After the failure of the **DocumentProperties API** I tried to put the
   print commands and got the following results:

   - My office printer (**Kyocera FS-C5100**) successfully printed a document
     on both sides, BUT came crazy and began to print each paragraph on a
     separate sheet...
   - Clients printer (**Xerox 3600**) apparently was "not fully HP-compatible" and did not print on both sides at all!

So my investigation continues and if anyone have other ideas - welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can not been solved directly, but it is possible to implement a workaround.

One "physical" printer should be installed on the client system several times, so that in the printers list it should be listed twice under different names.

Further, one of these "printers" must be configured to double side printing, and second to normal - one side printing. Depending on the application needs it selects one of two "printers" for printing documents.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Microsoft KB Article on [HOWTO: Set Duplex Printing for Word Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230743), unfortunately it is not a simple property you set.  It is VB code, but it should be pretty easy to convert to C#.

If you know you are using a PCL compatible printer, you can use print commands inside the document to force it to be duplex.  This is really helpful when you need to switch between simplex and duplex mid document.  You can add a field to the header of the document and then use 27"&l1S" or 27"&l2S" for duplex long and duplex short respectively.  A full list of PCL print commands are available from a [Microsoft KB article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135569)

Comment: Thanx @John! It looks like true solution! :) I'll try it tomorrow at work and write what I got!

Answer (score 0):

Call the [PrintOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.printout.aspx) method of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document object with ManualDuplexPrint parameter set to true.

Comment: it would be too easy :) I knew about this option, and tried to use it - no effect. Have you got to print on both sides in auto-duplex mode with it?