# How to print a Word.Document on both sides in C#?

Tags: c#

**Quick summary**

I am able to print out a Word document in C# using `PrintOut()` function like so:

```
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document doc = null;
        object template = @"/path/Template.docx";
        doc = app.Documents.Open(template, ReadOnly: true);
        app.Visible = false;

        // Print here
        doc.PrintOut();
```

**Problem**

What I realized is I can't print the document on both pages, if there are 2 pages. The 2 pages print 2 sheets, instead of printing on both sides.

I had a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.PrintOut nowhere it says anything about Printing on Both sides.

**Question**

What is a good method to print a `Word.Document` in C# on both sides of paper?

Comment: The document you linked to suggests you might be able to use `ManualDuplexPrint` if the step of manually flipping the paper works for you - ie if your printer doesn't _really_ support two sided printing.

Comment: You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467412/office-interop-word-how-to-print-the-document-on-both-sides).

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yeah, already tried that. Trying to make it simple as possible.

Comment: Looks like there's an approach [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/how-to-set-duplex-printing-for-microsoft-word-automation-clients-in-c-vb-net) - essentially you need to set the printer driver setting before doing what you're already doing above.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks for that, I'll try it out now.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Would you know what `using` reference is used to find `DuplexSettings`?

Comment: It's some custom code included in a zip file attached to that blog post - essentially all the win32 API calls to work with the driver are packaged up in that class

Comment: Here? https://support.microsoft.com/kb/828638 404 Page Not Found if thats the one you are referring to.

Comment: No, down at the bottom - _"[PrinterDuplexSettings.zip](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/30/70/74/PrinterDuplexSettings.zip)"_

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ahh I see.. Also in the meantime I will test this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142376/12485722

Answer (score 0):

It should be a setting you can change in the physical printer if that doesn't work try calling the PrintOut() method of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document object with ManualDuplexPrint parameter set to true.